# Multiprocessing, остановить потоки, выполнить действие, продолжить выполнение потоков

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность

На python3, есть класс с многопоточностью(на multiprocessing),
в нём есть метод, который выполняется потоково, необходимо: если данный метод возвращает(либо вызывает определённый триггер), остановить выполнение потоков, выполнить другой метод(не потоковый) и продолжить выполнение потоков. Пробовал использовать event - он выполяется и вызывается метод, но остальные работают некорректно.

Возможно ли, выполняя потоки, при получении(возвращении) определённого значения, остановить их, выполнить метод, после чего возобновить их работу?

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

class MyThread():

    def action(self,number):
        self.counter+=1 
        if self.counter>5:
            #остановить потоки
            #self.another_action - выполнить другое действие
            #возобновить потоки
        else:
            print("Thread {} done".format(number))

    def another_action(self):
        print("This is another action")
        return True

    def run(self):
        self.counter=0
        lst = [1,2,3,4,5,4,5,8,9,10]
        while True:
            pool = ThreadPool(5)  # старт потоков
            results = pool.map(self.action,lst)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

**UPD:**В результате использование Barrier, происходит остановка только одного потока, остальные продолжают выполняться:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import Barrier
from time import sleep


class Thread():
    def __init__(self):
        self.barrier = Barrier(5) #барьер на 5 потоков
        self.counter = 0 #счётчик

    def another_function(self):
        print("execute another function")
        sleep(10)
        print("end execute another function")

    def thread_func(self,step):
        self.counter+=step #добавляем значение к счётчику
        if self.counter>10: #если счётчик стал больше 10
            i = self.barrier.wait() #ставим барьер
            if i==0: 
                print("BARRIER - counter>10") #выводим сообщение 
                self.another_function() #запускаем другую функцию
        print("Thread for {}".format(step)) #вывод об успешном завершении потока

    def threaded_count(self,steps):
        pool = ThreadPool(5)  # старт потоков
        lst = [i for i in range(0,steps)] #создаём список чисел от 0 до 10
        pool.map(self.thread_func,lst) #потково выполняем  thread_func c аргументом из lst
        pool.start()
        pool.join()
        pool.close()


x = Thread()
x.threaded_count(11)
```

Comment: Выглядит как повод использовать [барьер](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Barrier).

Comment: в коде множество ошибок (проще с нуля начать, чем исправлять). Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Почему вы думаете, что потоки нужно "остановить"? Что происходит, если их не остановить? Что бы вы хотели, чтобы происходило вместо этого?

Comment: @jfs  это черновой набросок, для того чтобы в общих чертах описать ситуацию. 
Есть метод, который выполняется потоково, необходимо: 
если данный метод возвращает(либо вызывает определённый триггер), остановить выполнение потоков, выполнить другой метод(не потоковый) и продолжить выполнение потоков. Пробовал использовать event - он выполяется и вызывается метод, но остальные работают некорректно

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev использование барьера, не остановило остальные потоки, только первый поток, который "поймал" условие (добавил код в описание)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нужно использовать Lock()
в данном случае multithreading.Lock()

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import Lock
from time import sleep


class Thread():
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0 #счётчик
        self.lock = Lock()

    def another_function(self):
        print("execute another function")
        sleep(10)
        print("end execute another function")

    def thread_func(self,step):
        self.counter+=step #добавляем значение к счётчику
        if self.counter>10: #если счётчик стал больше 10
            with self.lock:
                print("LOCK - counter>10") #выводим сообщение 
                self.another_function() #запускаем другую функцию


        print("Thread for {}".format(step)) #вывод об успешном завершении потока

    def threaded_count(self,steps):
        pool = ThreadPool(5)  # старт потоков
        lst = [i for i in range(0,steps)] #создаём список чисел от 0 до 10
        pool.map(self.thread_func,lst) #потково выполняем  thread_func c аргументом из lst
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        pool.terminate()


x = Thread()
x.threaded_count(11)
```