# Замена многократного цикла на потоки для ускорения запросов к серверу

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность

Здравствуйте программисты! Имеется скрипт который делает постоянны запросы к серверу, и далее производит вычисления. Время отправки-получения запроса длиться около 2 сек. количество таких запросов к примеру 100, соответственно выполнение функции занимает приличное время. Хотелось бы переделать мой скрипт через потоки так как время многократно сократиться. 
Пытался переделать мой скрипт через потоки по примеру [Multiprocessing, остановить потоки, выполнить действие, продолжить выполнение потоков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810776/) вроде получилось но алгоритм какой-то нерациональный получился, поэтому прошу вашей помощи в переработке кода.
Вот мой скрипт через обычные циклы.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

#словарь начальных значений
tim0=datetime.now()
nachalo=tim0
mas0={'var1':10,'var2':22}
print('\n',tim0,'\nmas0',mas0)
g=0
while g<3:
    tik=1
    while tik < 5:
        time.sleep(1)

        #словарь конечных значений после интервала времени
        mas30={'var1':11,'var2':23.2}
        tim3=datetime.now()
        print('mas30',mas30)

        #разницы знвчений
        res={}
        for key, value in mas0.items():
              res[key] = float(mas30[key])-float(value)
        print('mas30-mas0',res)

        #максимальная разница
        maximum=max(res.items(), key=lambda k_v: k_v[1])
        print('maximum',maximum)

        #разница времени раньше и сейчас
        print('delta',(tim3-tim0).total_seconds())

        if maximum[1]>0:
            print('GOOD\n')

            ##блок блок операций

            mas30={'var1':11,'var2':23.2}
            tim3=datetime.now()
            break
        else: print('BED\n')

        tik=1+tik

        if tik==5:
            break
    print('Все\n\n')
    mas0=mas30
    tim0=tim3
    g+=1
print(datetime.now()-nachalo)
```

Comment: А где в коде отправка запросов?

Comment: Я запросы не писал в коде, чтобы не загромождать. Вместо них прописаны словари mas0 mas30 (после отправки запросов возвращаются словари )

Comment: Вы ведь хотите распараллелить запросы по сети? Пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/eca2484466a3788a67e2c787cfff2595889cdf1d/multithreading__example/example%20multiprocessing.dummy/hello_world.py

Comment: В принципе да, но при распараллеливании должно выполняться условие  например поиска максимума из результатов и в этот момент остальные 99 потоков блокироватьс а после все по новой.

Comment: а как вы узнаете максимальный результат, пока не переберете все запросы? Да и если пока один запрос в потоке выполняется, остальные потоки блокируются, это не отличается от синхронного способа

Comment: Внутри каждого из  100 потоков, которые направляют запросы и получают результаты в виде словарей, внутри элементов этих словарей ищется максимальный элемент . Если этот элемент в каком-то из потоков найден остальные блокируются (какой-то запрос  раньше результат вернул, какой-то позже) происходит выход ну а далее по-новой.

Comment: В моем коде через циклы количество потоков это 5 а не 100

Comment: чтобы несколько запросов одновременно выполнить: [How to parallelized file downloads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31784484/4279), [Problem with multi threaded Python app and socket connections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4783735/4279)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [A very simple multithreading parallel URL fetching (without queue)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16181121/4279)